# Properties of reflected light

Tags: optics, reflection

When light is reflected from an object, the wavelength of the reflected light represents the colour  of the surface of the object. How are other properties of the surface, such as shininess, represented?

Comment: Do you mean specular reflection? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection

Comment: Thank you, that looks like the answer. Presumably the eye detects that all rays entering it are parallel so the object is seen as shiny, not matt.